# android RGB565 format bitmap

Tags: java, android, bitmap

I am trying to display an image on Anki Vector robot.
My Android app draws the bitmap from a canvas and then uses "createBitmap" method to convert it to the RGB_565 format. Because the display is specified as RGB565 here:
https://vector.ikkez.de/generated/anki_vector.screen.html#module-anki_vector.screen

createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

Result seems successful but color channels are not correct.

RGB was ordered like BRG.
As a workaround I swapped channels accordingly.
But now orange and yellow colors seems to be swapped.
When I draw orange , display shows yellow. When I draw yellow, it shows orange.
What may be the problem ?

FOr swapping channels I used following code:

```
public Bitmap swapC(Bitmap srcBmp) {

    int width = srcBmp.getWidth();
    int height = srcBmp.getHeight();

    float srcHSV[] = new float[3];
    float dstHSV[] = new float[3];

    Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            int pixel = srcBmp.getPixel(col, row);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
            int redC = Color.red(pixel);
            int greenC = Color.green(pixel);
            int blueC = Color.blue(pixel);
            dstBitmap.setPixel(col, row, Color.argb(alpha,blueC,redC,greenC));
        }
    }

    return dstBitmap;
}
```

Comment: I see nothing that would limit to five or expand to six bits. –

Comment: Green has six bits in RGB but five in BRG. So you have to adapt.

Comment: How do you display an image on the robot's screen? What library/ies and methods do you use? I would have expected the library to do the required color space conversion when necessary

Comment: @blackapps how can I adapt to that green bits being 5 in BRG ?

Comment: @Joni there is a protobuf library that I use and it just requires a ByteString for the image. There's no auto conversion.

Comment: You adapt the bits by some calculations.

Comment: thank you ; that was really very explaining...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used a workaround as a solution; dividing color channel values by 8 :

```
public Bitmap swapC(Bitmap srcBmp) {

    int width = srcBmp.getWidth();
    int height = srcBmp.getHeight();

    float srcHSV[] = new float[3];
    float dstHSV[] = new float[3];

    Bitmap dstBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
            int pixel = srcBmp.getPixel(col, row);
            int alpha = Color.alpha(pixel);
            int redC = Color.red(pixel);
            int greenC = Color.green(pixel);
            int blueC = Color.blue(pixel);
            dstBitmap.setPixel(col, row, Color.argb(alpha,blueC/8,redC/8,greenC/8));
        }
    }

    return dstBitmap;
}
```